# Riddle: Another name for Noach

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, riddle, noach-noah-the-man

What was Noach's other name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Menachem](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40009&st=&pgnum=24).

Comment: Contrast this with Rashi Bereshit 5:29: http://www.tachash.org/metsudah/b01r.html#fn309

Answer (score 2):

Utnapishtim?

;-)

Comment: don't get it. Can u explain?

Comment: They heard it from Avraham and stole it from us just like all the other similar Histories
yydl see here
http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread208408/pg1